# loadFromFile SFML C++

Tags: c++, sfml

Вообщем

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML");

    sf::Texture texture;

    texture.loadFromFile("1.png");
```

Вот часть кода, при отладке появляется ошибка, компилятор(Visual Studio) указывает на эту строку `texture.loadFromFile("1.png");`
С ошибкой:

> `Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x0FA1E367 (vcruntime140.dll) в test.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00395000.`

Comment: Файл существует? Какой у него размер? Попробуйте полный путь подставить.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас неправильно подключена библиотека. см: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131393/sfml-error-loadfromfile

Answer (score 2):

Ты написал путь так, что сам файл у тебя должен быть в папке с исходным кодом проги.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]